# Using dotenv with bundled client side code

Tags: node.js, gulp, environment-variables, contentful-management

I am creating a node js application as a Contentful UI Extension. The code is hosted here: https://github.com/doodybrains/media-tagging-extension

A lot of the gulp file is boiler plate but in the end everything gets bundled into an `index.html` file. I know that env variables shouldn't be called or processed in the client code but I don't know how to get them in there before the project is built. When I run the repo in development and call `process.env.NAME_OF_TOKEN` from `src/index.js` it returns `undefined`. I have tried import dotenv, creating a gulp env pipeline etc.

ANY ADVICE will be so helpful. The app is being deployed to Netlify and I already have the env variables set up there as well.

thank you

Comment: I don't think you can use env inside your src/index.js since it's client side, and gulp cannot precompile that for you, either. Maybe you should import those vars from a json file instead of a dotenv file?

Comment: I like the idea but how do I use the json file without submitting it to source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another js file which can use NODE_ENV to set correct variable.
I prefer calling a service to get all my properties on app start and set in some map. I use the map to set the value in different places in my code.

Some sample code...

```js
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'local';
const sit = {
    URL: 'sit url',
    HOST: 'sit host',
    ENV: 'sit'
};
const uat = {
    URL: 'uat url',
    HOST: 'uat host',
    ENV: 'uat'
};

var property_service_url = config[env].URL;
var property_service_host = config[env].HOST;
```

Before starting your app, you can set the NODE_ENV=environment. For example in linux.

```
export NODE_ENV=uat
```

This will make sure that environment set correctly. Now in your app.js for , you can call the service to load your properties. If you don't want to call a service, you can set it in the same way the URL and HOST are set.